# How to insert data into postgis database table?

Tags: postgis, database

I am a newbie in spatial database, so I am having lots of issues even in small tasks and now I am having some issue with inserting data to the table. I have followed the postgis documentation but however, I'm getting some error while inserting data to the table. 
In the code below, I am trying to insert an array of co-ordinates which are in long/lat format by converting them into points and adding to the table.

INSERT INTO route(ID, ROUTE_NAME, geom)
VALUES (1, 'route 1', ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(ST_MakePoint(27.69858, 85.28154), ST_MakePoint(27.69804, 85.28155), ST_MakePoint(27.69337, 85.28174), ST_MakePoint(27.69356, 85.28275), ST_MakePoint(27.69378, 85.28370), ST_MakePoint(27.69409, 85.28449))',900913));

Table create structure:
CREATE TABLE ROUTE( ID int4, ROUTE_NAME varchar(25), geom geometry(LINESTRING,900913) );

But, I am getting "LINESTRING(ST" <-- parse error at position 13 within geometry error.

Comment: Try googling what the Well Known Text string should contain -- hint: it's a text string with coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `ST_MakePoint`, just chain your coordinates in `ST_GeomFromText`. You can just write something like `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(27.69858 85.28154, 27.69804 85.28155, 27.69337 85.28174, 27.69356 85.28275, 27.69378 85.28370, 27.69409 85.28449)', 900913)`. x and y parts of coordinates are separated by space, coordinate-pairs by commas. See also the [ST_GeomFromText documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html) for more information.

Comment: Well its working very well now. But i have one more  concern,  that is there any way to convert the longitude/latitude to the Point and add to the table at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want to achieve? Why you would want to convert a latitude/longitude coordinate into a point? If inserting a point is what you need, just do it by ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.69858 85.28154)'). If you want to "convert" from Latitude/Longitude to another reference system, use `ST_Transform`.

Comment: what i mean is that I want to store co-ordinates in the form of point(x,y) format instead of long/lat. So, I have array of long/lat data and I want to convert it into point before storing it into the table. In above case, whenever I select st_astext(geom), i simply get linestring of long/lat but what I want is to have line string of points instead of long/lat when i do st_astext(geom). BTW, i need this table's data to compute with another table data which is in point(x,y) format and also i don't want any extra conversion during computing if I can directly store in point form in this table.

Comment: PostGIS does note make the difference between lat/long and x/y. It simply has a spatial reference system associated identified by its EPSG code. If it is a geographic reference system, it is automatically in lat/long, and if it is a projected reference system, in x/y. If you had lat/long coordinates in WSG84 (EPSG 4326), and you want to store them let's say in Google Mercator (EPSG 3857), you could do `ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(27.69858 85.28154, ...)', 4326), 3857)`.

Comment: Thanx, it is really helpful and now I am very clear. Also, I found that there is no necessarily convert lat/long to point. Somehow with your information I made some changes in my code and its working like a charm.